# Solving ODE numerically when the coefficient of the highest order term is near zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve an ODE of an inharmonic oscillator including an extraordinary type of the external force numerically. It is written as follows:

$ x^{\prime\prime}(t) + f(t) x^{\prime}(t) + k^2 x(t) = F(x^{\prime\prime\prime\prime},x^{\prime\prime\prime},k,t) $,

where $f$ is a function of time, $k$ is a frequency, and the function $F$ represents the external force exhibiting some instability of the system. What makes the equation tricky to solve is that the external force is explicitly dependent on the higher derivatives of the position of the oscillator, defined by

$ F(x^{\prime\prime\prime\prime},x^{\prime\prime\prime},k,t) \equiv \alpha \{ A(k,t) x^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}(t) + B(k,t) x^{\prime\prime\prime}(t) \} $,

where $\alpha$ is a free parameter representing the strength of the external source, and $A, B$ are complex combinations of $k,t$.

The problem is that I want to solve it numerically when the parameter $\alpha$ is near zero, including when $\alpha=0$, as I want to see a solution of $x(t)$ approaches to the behavior of typical oscillators.

I have already checked that it can be solved without problem in Mathematica, using its built-in function 'NDSolve.' However, The equation needs to be solved repeatedly to conduct a Monte-Carlo simulation. And for this task, Mathematica is too slow and heavy. So I'm trying to make a code solving the equation in C or Python(if code in C doesn't work well). But I have no idea how to deal with it when $\alpha$ approaches zero. To be detailed, to solve the equation numerically in these languages, I have to rewrite it somewhat like this:

```
deriv(x_ddd) = ( - B(k,t)*x_ddd + x_dd + f(t)*x_d + k*k*x ) / A(k,t)/alpha
deriv(x_dd) = x_ddd
deriv(x_d) = x_dd
deriv(x) = x_d
```

Because 'deriv(x_ddd)' diverges as $\alpha\rightarrow0$, the code fails to solve it numerically.

So my question is, is there any mathematical trick or algorithm avoiding this issue? I guess this question is maybe more connected with programming techniques. However, I want to be sure first if there is any purely mathematical remedy as I wish to obtain the solution as exact as possible.

I'd like to note that the function $f(t)$ can be considered a constant $f_0$, although this assumption is valid only in some particular cases. So if you wish to, you can regard the solution of the equation as a standard form of $e^{-a t} \cos(b t + c)$ when $\alpha=0$.

Comment: You have a simpler but similar situation with the Vander Pol oscillator for large parameters, or rewritten to be similar, $(x^2-1)x'=α(x''+x)$, where you can decompose the dynamic into fast and slow phases and find separate approximations for both. Boundary layer problems share the multi-scale nature with these more dynamical situations.

Comment: Are you sure that anything interesting can happen, except in the initial phase? The short-term fast dynamic will push $x''$ to the value $-k^2x-fx'$ or explode to infinity in a time $\sim α^{-1/2}$, depending on the sign of the real part of $A$. After that no "interesting" break-out of the slow dynamic of the order-2 oscillation is possible, if $Re(A)$ does not change its sign from negative to positive, which should lead to immediate divergence. In the stable case, the defect of the left side will not be zero, but some very small number.

Comment: Can you give a typical case, best would be simplified to constants, that gives typical observed behavior or sensible results in the Mathematica simulations? Or alternatively describe in more detail the surrounding situation? The reason I ask is because the short-term fast behavior is dominated by the dynamic $W=AW''$, $W(s)\approx x''(t_0+α^{1/2}s)$, and this has no stably converging solutions on the microscopic scale, so it is hard to see that you will get sensible results on the macroscopic scale for $α\to 0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think I understand what you mean, as the system is unstable. The value of $\alpha$ should be so really small, and what I'm interested in here is small additional fluctuation(or fast phases) around the original oscillation. I'm trying to construct mathematical modeling of a fluctuating physical system and verify whether my hypothesis would be allowed given some data.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Here is a simplified example of Mathematica code. Although it seems unstable for some value of $\alpha$, I think that this might clarify what I mean here.
`
Subscript[t, ini] = 10^-5;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] + 
     k^2 x[t] == -\[Alpha] (k^2  x''''[t] + k t x'''[t]), 
   x[Subscript[t, ini]] == 10, x'[Subscript[t, ini]] == 0, 
   x''[Subscript[t, ini]] == 0, x'''[Subscript[t, ini]] == 0}, 
  x, {t, Subscript[t, ini], 50}, {k, \[Alpha]}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[x[5, \[Alpha]][t] /. sol], {t, Subscript[t, ini], 
   10}], {\[Alpha], 10^-6, 5*10^-6}]
`

Comment: That should work if you make the decay a part of the dominating short term behavior. This would require $x''+fx'+k^2x=-α^2Ax''''-αBx'''$, $A,B$ positive. Then the short term behavior on time scale $α$ around some time point $t_0$, that is, $t=t_0+αS$, is dominated by $X''(s)=-AX''''(s)-BX'''(s)$, so a falling oscillation that leads back to the locally linear trend that belongs to the slow dynamic. However, this does not have a mechanism that produces discrepancies spontaneously like in the canard dynamic of Van der Pol.

Comment: A weakly related example for periodic spontaneous small oscillations is the application of Heun's method with a too large step size to the VdP oscillator, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361336/how-can-i-stop-my-runge-kutta2-heun-method-from-exploding

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you. I'll try to check whether that is applicable to my case.

Comment: In your pseudo-code, it should be `deriv(x_ddd) = ( - B(k,t)*x_ddd + (x_dd + f(t)*x_d + k*k*x)/alpha ) / A(k,t)`, if that is wrong also in the actual code this might explain some discrepancies.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh, I made a mistake in the pseudocode. The original code is correct. Anyway, thank you!